# How to move nodes into an array and key into the given node in Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have `JSON` payload like this;

```
[
   {
      "Samples":{
         "Load":{
            "itemId":"bx",
            "timestamp":"2019-01-28T16:13:39.387640Z",
            "name":null
         },
         "Press":{
            "itemId":"by",
            "timestamp":"2019-01-28T16:13:39.387640Z",
            "name":null
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I want receive `JSON` like below:

```
{
   "Samples":{
      "Items":[
         {
            "tag_name":"Load",
            "itemId":"bx",
            "timestamp":"2019-01-28T16:13:39.387640Z",
            "name":null
         },
         {
            "tag_name":"Press",
            "itemId":"by",
            "timestamp":"2019-01-28T16:13:39.387640Z",
            "name":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I do this? Can I use `JolTransformRecord`? Does this record suit for real-time streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using very similar problem from GitHub: [Could you please assist me ? Moving nodes up into an array, and the key into the nodes](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/273) you can find out solution. Example which first copies to array the whole object and after that adds `tag_name`:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Samples": {
          "*": { // keys: Load or Press
            // Left hand side "@" means grab the whole object 
            //  that was the right hand side of Load or Press.
            // Then send it to Samples.Items array.
            "@": "Samples.Items[#2]",
            "$": "Samples.Items[#2].tag_name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much both edit and answer! Your response is great for me! But I don't understand that what does "#2" means?

Comment: Take a look on this [example](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#mapToList). It counts how many nodes `Samples` node has.

Comment: Thank you so much! As seen [how-to-convert-xml-to-json-with-new-json-structure-in-nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842661/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-with-new-json-structure-in-nifi) this question; Is it possible to convert xml to json in Nifi?