# How to convert XML to JSON with new JSON structure in Nifi?

Tags: json, xml, apache-nifi

I get different `XML`s from web services. I want to convert this `XML` to `JSON`, but structure must be changed.

For example, I have `XML` structure like this;

```
<root>
    <A attr="attr1">VAL</A>
    <B attr="attr2">VAL</B>
</root>
```

And result of `JSON` that I want.

```
{
   "root":{
      "Items":[
         {
            "tag_name":"A",
            "attr":"attr1",
            "value":"VAL"
         },
         {
            "tag_name":"B",
            "attr":"attr2",
            "value":"VAL"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I do this in `Nifi`? `ConvertRecord` or `UpdateRecord`? Also, how should read and write schema for this if record based processors may be used?

Comment: only scipt i guess

Comment: I can use TransformXML using XSLT, but it is to slow. Is there another option for this? such as JoltTransformRecord, UpdateRecord, ConvertRecord etc..

Comment: Do you use any libraries?  By `Nifi` you means [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/developer-guide.html)? Can you use `Jackson` lib for example?

Comment: Yes, Apache Nifi. In fact, I wonder that can this operation be done in Nifi without any script.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a pure NiFi flow, the steps to do this are:

1. Convert the XML to JSON, this can be done with a ValidateRecord processor, you must define the schema of the json, so during this step you are going to check that the input data is ok.
2. Modify the JSON structure using the JoltTransform processor.

Comment: Don't got your point, you were speaking about json files, not streaming.